# LightOpenID google example just doesn't work

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I was transferred to a new project based on php so I've spent last week building my php skills. Today I wanted to make a login page based on google account. It looked like LightOpenID will suffice but I can't get their [example](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/example-google.php) to work. Whatever I try I always get "User has not logged in.". It seems to me that validation is always returning false although when I sign in on Google and return to my page I can see data in that GET request with the openid.claimed_id and more parameters.

Since I'm behind company proxy, I've also run this on aws but no luck.

Do I need to configure my server in any way to enable this, cause it should work. Some PHP or Apache configuration? I'm putting my ip in constructor since I don't have a domain but that is only for show I think anyway.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. Did you run it from your computer, or a server? If from a server, did you modify the constructor parameter accordingly?

Comment: Both from my computer and from aws micro instance running Ubuntu 11.04. When running from aws I've put IP in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to install curl. A simple apt-get install php5-curl did the trick. I've paid a price to my php n00bness I guess.